# Ruby on Rails: validation depending on locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-i18n

I have a multilingual project with, say, English and Russian locales.
I want such a validation:

*example.com/**en**/book/new* <- in a text field here it's only **ASCII** symbols available.

*example.com/**ru**/book/new* <- in a text field here it's only **cyrillic** symbols available.

What's the best way to do that?

I have an idea to use '**validates ... if ...**' in models.

But what am I going to do if I have many models and I want to add just another locale?

Maybe there're some ways to keep such validations in a single file like i18n *.yml's?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators) and include it in the models you wish to validate

`I18n.locale` will return your current locale

Use it in a `case` statement to inside your custom validator to make language-specific checks

```
    case I18n.locale
    when :en
      # check for latin characters
    when :ru
      # check for cyrillic characters
    else
      return true
    end
```